# Generate apk for GDK and compile them on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, google-gdk

I am developing a sample GDK App.I am able to run an emulator using this http://pathofacoder.com/2013/07/19/installing-google-glass-in-an-android-phone/,

But the problem is how I will compile the sample app on Glass Emulator i.e. how I can generate the apk of sample project developed in GDK.

Comment: Wouldn't you just use the Android Developer Tools (ADT) to develop and compile an API for a Google Glass project the same as you would when planning to target Google Glass itself? {Note: I have not experience trying to put GlassWare on an Android emulator since none appear to support Google Glass yet.

Comment: Since there is no target device to install the apk(real gogole glass device or virtual emulator for glass),due to which it does not build nay apk.Is there is any alternate way to build the apk.